# Need a really simple client manage script to deliver graphics and revisions, please help?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, management, clients

I am looking for a very simple client management script.

The process flow of the script should be:

Client orders (paypal etc) while giving specs on what they need > given login details and thanked for their order > backend for them consists of a 2 way communication. They ask questions we answer. We also upload the graphics here where they either accept them or as for revision. > process complete.

Now I cannot for the life of me find something as simple as this. It seems all the scripts out there are way too complicated.

Does anyone know of one I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty simple to use and cheap

http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-client-manager-lite-edition/47626